# Command line perl: exit after condition no longer met

Tags: perl, command-line, text-processing

I want to print all header lines of a file:

```
perl -wnl -e "/^#/ and print" file.vcf
```

This works- however, I want to quit after I'm done with the header.

What's wrong with

```
perl -wnl -e "/^#/ and print else exit" file.vcf
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`else` is a keyword that's found as part of `if` and `unless` statements.

```
perl -wnl -e "if (/^#/) { print } else { exit }" file.vcf

perl -wnl -e "/^#/ ? print : exit" file.vcf

perl -wnl -e "/^#/ or exit; print" file.vcf

perl -wpl -e "/^#/ or exit" file.vcf

perl -wpl -e "/^#/ or last" file.vcf

perl -p -e "/^#/ or last" file.vcf

perl -pe"/^#/ or last" file.vcf
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
perl -wnl -e "/^#/ ? print : exit" file.vcf
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
perl -wnl -e "/^#/ && print or exit" file.vcf
```